# How to access characters of concatenated string in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to write a function that accesses every n-th element of this concatenated string:

```
var grid = ( 
  "1 \n" +
  "a 2 F C A E A E ! \n" +
  "G H 3 E L A T \n" +
  "L M N E P U F \n" +
  "X Z R P L")
```

For instance, the number 1 in the first string, the number 2 in the second string etc. Right now, I already don't know how I can access e.g. the second string. I tried

```
console.log(grid[3])
```

and

```
console.log(grid[3][0])
```

but basically have no idea, how to access the elements of the second, third strings etc. Thanks for reading!

Comment: After the strings are concatenated, there is only **one** string.

Comment: You mean the first character on each line (after line break)? It would be easier to keep the individual strings in an array as long as possible and only concatenate them when you need to print it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like that

```js
let grid = 
  "1 \n" +
  "a 2 F C A E A E ! \n" +
  "G H 3 E L A T \n" +
  "L M N E P U F \n" +
  "X Z R P L"
 
function getByCoordinates(a, x, y){
 return a.split('\n').map(x => x.split(' '))[y][x]
}

console.log(getByCoordinates(grid,0,3))
```

As mentioned in the comments above this is just a string, so there is no build-in method but you can play around with it in anyway you like.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to opperate it as an array. Notice that in order to access one of the digit elements, you must use the value of that digit minus 1, because arrays in javascript are 0 index based.

```js
  const grid =
      "1 \n" +
      "a 2 F C A E A E ! \n" +
      "G H 3 E L A T \n" +
      "L M N E P U F \n" +
      "X Z R P L";

  const asArray = grid
    .split("\n") // Creates an array of lines.
    .map((row) => row.split(" ")); // Creates an array of "characters" from each line, effectively producing a two dimensinal array.

  console.log(asArray[2][2]); // Prints "3".
```